# Google Reader Unread Count

Tags: php, api, google-reader, read-unread

I wrote this function to get the unread count of google reader items.

```
function GetUnread($sid)
{
    $url = "http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/unread-count?all=true&output=xml";
    $msg = urldecode($msg);
    $msg = stripslashes($msg);
    $msg = urlencode($msg);
    $url = $url . $msg;

    $purl = parse_url($url);
    $uri = $purl['scheme'] . "://" . $purl['host'] . $purl['path'] . "?" . $purl['query'];

    $cookie = "Name=SID;SID=" . $sid . ";Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=16000000";

    $headers = array();
    array_push($headers, "GET " . $uri . " HTTP/1.0");
    array_push($headers, "Host: " . $purl['host']);
    array_push($headers, "Referer: " . $uri);
    array_push($headers, "Cookie: " . $cookie);
    array_push($headers, "");
    $headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);

    echo $headers;

    $conn = fsockopen($purl['host'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if ($conn)
    {
        fputs($conn, $headers);
        $response = "";
        while (!feof($conn)) //Appears to loop indefinitely until feof's timeout(60)
        {
            $response .= fgets($conn, 128);
        }
        fclose($conn);
    }

    echo $response;
}
```

The headers when produced look like this:

```
GET http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/unread-count?all=true&output=xml HTTP/1.0
Host: www.google.com
Referer: http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/unread-count?all=true&output=xml
Cookie: Name=SID;SID=DQA...zA;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=16000000
```

It just sits there and once finished loading there is no response string. Is it an issue with the headers or the fsockopen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly try simplifying the url you're trying to get (just try google.com). If that returns a response there's a chance there could be some sort of authentication issue.

Comment: I tried all sorts of combinations, I have ended up using cUrl